# Content gets deleted from a mountpoint after reboot

Tags: mount, fstab

I created a mount point in an existing setup with this command:

```
mount -o loop /comptel
```

and made an entry to `/etc/fstab` as well which looks like this:

```
#tmpfs   /comptel       tmpfs   defaults,loop,size=110,mode=1777,dev,exec,suid  0       0
tmpfs   /comptel       tmpfs   rw,nosuid,nodev,size=110,noatime,user,uid=1000,gid=1001,mode=1777   0       0
```

This looks in `df -kh` like this:

```
tmpfs           4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /comptel
```

But when i reboot the setup, contents from `/comptel` gets deleted. 
Can someone please help me with this issue? What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using ‘TMPFS’

Comment: I have a little clue about it. i tried using ext4 as well. But something strange happened and within /comptel i could see complete filesystem of / so i reverted that.

Answer (score 0):

You could be making a typo or some mistake in `/etc/fstab`

Steps to mount a disk permanently.
Doing this will mount your disk during boot time.

0. Attach your disk manually once.
1. Goto `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab` and look for your mount entry.
2. Copy the entry that you want to be mounted on boot.
3. Paste it at the end of `/etc/fstab`. `/etc/fstab` Contains entries that are mounted during boot.

You can even manually add your entry in `/etc/fstab`, but copying it from `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab` makes sure that you not make any error or mistake in listing your mount point

more helpful links [link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux)     [link 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218859/permanently-mount-reboot-currently-stops)